# Python/Powershell/Batch script to move file from one location to another via Parameter for file name?

Tags: python

I would like to implement within my python script, a process to move files from one location to another, based off of parameter that will be inserted to get the file name (ideally a wildcard) .. I am going to implement this into a loop and it file names will change as it loops through, so i will want to be able to pick these files up based off their names.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:

Now I have taken the suggestion from Trotta (thanks) and have a code sample which I have tried to use. I have made it into a python function with a parameter. The parameter will be constantly changing within the loop, also I do not need to rename the file, just simply move it from one directory to another. However it does not appear to be picking it up. I have created source directory 'release_deployment_scripts' and the target directory 'test_delete' within the root directory of my python project/environment but it's not picking any up. FYI the 2 files I have in the source folder are both 'PostDeploy_BI-Test.sql' and 'PreDeploy_BI_Test.sql' ... do you know what i'm doing wrong? Code below:

```
import glob
import shutil


def add_deployment_files(Jira):
    list_of_files = glob.glob('/release_deployment_scripts/*' + Jira + '*') #source file(s)
    for file in list_of_files:
        print(file)
        new_path = '/test_delete/' # target destination 
        shutil.move(file, new_path)

add_deployment_files('BI-Test')
```

Comment: Asking for help suggests you've done some work, but you haven't shown us it. Post your [tag:powershell] script, your [tag:batch-file] and your [tag:cmd] command line as well as your [tag:python] script. If you don't have all of those, remove the tags you don't need, post the content you have and formulate a proper question accoding to [ask]. _Please note that this site provides assistance in fixing specific issues with your provided code, it doesn't write code for you to your list of specifications._

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have updated the question. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Can you provide the error message? And does that print statement properly return your files?

Comment: Hello, must have been something to do with the paths, i stored them into variables and it seemed to work fine: correct code below

def add_deployment_files(Jira):
    source = 'C:/mypath/release_deployment_scripts/'
    dest = 'C:/mypath/test_delete/'
    list_of_files = glob.glob(source + '*' + Jira + '*')
    for file in list_of_files:
        print(file)
        shutil.move(file, dest)

add_deployment_files('BI-Test')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to do that in python would be to work with `glob` and `shutil`. You could fetch specific files with glob (that allows the use of wildcards) and move them to another path that you define beforehand:

```
import glob
import shutil

list_of_files = glob.glob('/path/to/directory/B*') # you can work with wildcards here; in this example you would fetch all files in this directory starting with a 'B'
for file in list_of_files:
    new_name = '/new/path/filename' # create new name for the file
    shutil.move(file, new_name)
```

As it is not apparent from your question how you would want to implement this into a loop, I assume you'll be able to adapt this snippet to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question using a modified version of your code. Hopefully you can help.